# gensim LDAModel early stopping

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim, lda, early-stopping

Gensim [LDAModel](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_lda.html) has parameters `iterations` and `passes` to control the number of training epochs, and callbacks to get information about convergence, but is there a possibility to stop the training when difference between two epochs is very small i.e. early stopping?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to break the Word2vec training from a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134062/how-to-break-the-word2vec-training-from-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities that is mentioned in an answer to the question [How to break the Word2vec training from a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134062/how-to-break-the-word2vec-training-from-a-callback-function) is to raise a custom exception in case the conditions for an early stop are met.

Class `gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel` has an optional parameter `callbacks` accepting a list of [`gensim.models.callbacks.Callback`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/callbacks.html#gensim.models.callbacks.Callback)-s. I suggest you review the documentation.

Comment: I just noticed that LdaMulticore does not allow callbacks so this will not help. But could you explain how do you use callback in the case of LdaModel to partially train it? I can't find a working example of callback in ldamodel.